# Drupal webform with sortable report

Tags: forms, webforms

I want the **webform** submitted **report** to be **sortable** (or filtered), suppose there is the "Country" field in the form with **selectlist** of Countries,

I must be able to filter the reports with specific value,suppose "USA" or something else.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something? What was the issue you ran into?

Comment: I am playing with the webform report for a while now, I am asking for any recommendation on how the reports can be filtered or if there is any module for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Views to render a table view of fields (for Country, etc) and set the content filter of that view to pull only submitted webforms.

Comment: How do you set the content filter criteria for webform submissions, do not see that in the options list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with [Webform Report](https://drupal.org/project/webform_report) module, using filters.

- Install and configure the [Webform Report](https://drupal.org/project/webform_report) module
- Go to content > add new content > webform report
- Select a webform which you want to extract a report of submissions
- In "Report Criteria" section, select all the components (fields) from the webform that you want to display on your report.
- select the fields you want to use to create a filter, In your case choose:

  Type de filtre= equal, and Filter Value= USA